# Value of variable changes with unrelated code

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, uint64

I struggle with a bug since hours now. Basically, I do some simple bit operation on an uint64_t array in main.c (no function calls). It works properly on gcc (Ubuntu), MSVS2019 (Windows 10) in Debug, **but not in Release**. However my target architecture is x64/Windows, so I need to get it work properly with MSVS2019/Release. Besides that, I'm curious what the reason for the problem is. None of the compilers shows errors or warnings.

Now, as soon as I add a totally unrelated command to the loop (commented `printf()`), it works properly.

```
...
int q = 5;
uint64_t a[32] = { 0 };
// a[] is filled with data
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    a[q] = (a[q] << 2) | 8;
    // printf("%i \n", i); // that's the line which makes it work
}
...
```

Initially I believed that I messed up the stack somewhere before the `for()` loop, but I checked it up multiple times ... all fine!

- all used variables are checked to be initialized
- no pointer returns of local variables (in scope)
- array indexing (reads and writes) all within declaration limits (in scope)

All Google/SE posts explain subject UB to some of the above reasons, but none of these apply for my code. Also the fact, that it works in MSVS2019/Debug and gcc shows the code works.

What do I miss?

**--- UPDATE (24.08.2021 12:00) ---**

I'm completely stuck, since added `printf()` modifies the result and MSVS/Debug works. So how can I inspect variables?!

@Lev M There are quite some calculations before and after the shown `for()` loop. That's why I skipped most of the code and just showed the snippet where I could influence the code towards working correctly. I know what should be the final result (it's just a uint64_t), and it's wrong with the Release version of MSVS. I also checked w/o the `for()` loop. It's not optimized "away". If I leave it out completely, the result is again different.

@tstanisl It's just a matter of an uint64_t number. I know that input A should output B.

@Steve Summit That's why I posted (a bit desperate). I checked in all directions, isolated as much code as I could and yet ... no uninitialized variable or array out of bound. Driving me nuts.

@Craig Estey The code is unfortunately quite extensive. I wonder ... could the error also be in a part of the code which doesn't run?

@Eric Postpischil Agreed!

@Nate Eldredge I tested on valgrind (see below).

```
...
==13997== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13997==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13997==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==13997==
==13997== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==13997==
==13997== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**--- UPDATE (24.08.2021 18:00) ---**

I found the reason for the problem (after countless trial-and-errors), but no solution yet. I post more of the code.

```
...
int q = 5;
uint64_t a[32] = { 0 };
// a[] is filled with data
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    a[q] = (a[q] << 2) | 8;
    // printf("%i \n", i); // that's the line which makes it work
}
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    a[q] = (a[q] << 3) | 3;
}
...
```

In fact, the MSVS/Release compiler did this:

```
...
int q = 5;
uint64_t a[32] = { 0 };
// a[] is filled with data
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    a[q] = (a[q] << 2) | 8;
    a[q] = (a[q] << 3) | 3;
}
...
```

... which is not the same. Never seen such a thing!

How can I force the compiler to keep the 2 `for()` loops separate?

Comment: It might be an optimization issue - perhaps VS is somehow optimizing away the loop when you do a release build? What result are you getting in 'release' - data does not change? Random garbage?

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: The symptoms you've described almost always mean you've got an uninitialized local variable, or a local array that you're accessing outside the bounds of.  I know you've said you checked those, but I'd keep looking there!

Comment: The code you've posted _has_ to work. The issue must be in the code that you _didn't_ post. _What_ does it do [wrong] and _should_ it do? I suspect that the full code is small enough that you could _edit_ your question and post it.

Comment: Re “Also the fact, that it works in MSVS2019/Debug and gcc shows the code works”: That is not a valid logical inference.

Comment: Have you tried running under valgrind, AddressSanitizer, etc?

Comment: `In fact, the MSVS/Release compiler did this` because it is exactly what should be done. For the code you posted there is no difference between two and one `for` loop versions

Comment: @0___________ You are right I omitted an essential part. The index of array ``a[]`` is outside the ``for()`` loops. I corrected all code snippets by adding ``int q = 5;``. My apologies. However it doesn't change anything to the fact that only MSVS/Release does this attempt to optimize.

Comment: @geohei When you say "doesn't change anything" do you mean that adding `int q = 5` does not fix the problem, or that it *does* fix the problem, but doesn't fix the puzzle for you that you don't understand what happened when it wasn't there?

Comment: @geohei editing the question making comments not relevant is another bad habit

Comment: @geohei You're asking about two loops being treated differently.  But one loop you showed has `a[q]`, and one loop has `a[i]`.  What's going on?!?

Comment: @geohei You're probably going to need to find another way of solving this particular problem.  I don't think you're going to be able to describe it clearly and accurately enough for us to have any hope of understanding it or explaining it to you.

Comment: Ok ... I try to clean up the mess. ``int q = 5`` should have been in the snippets right from the beginning (my omit). The OP is now correct (after I re-edited it). Snippets are real code and the problem can be simulated. The problem is not **fixed** but just **identified**! The reason for the problem is that MSVS/Release merges the ´´for()´´ loops. I believe the OP should be clear now. IMHO it is a compiler doing too much optimization. Sorry for the generated confusion.

Comment: @geohei the first loop can be optimized out as it always will be 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa8 despite the initial value. Your code is simply wrong!!

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Pbj3K1nrz

Comment: The second loop is also not needed as it will produce the same value every time as first loop will produce the same result.

Comment: BTW discovered a missed gcc optimization\

Comment: The OP shows the minimum code to demonstrate the problem. Even if the first loop's result is always ``0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa8``, the entire code is much more complex (e.g. both loops are not limited to 32, but are variable conforming to % 8). MSVS/Release optimizes where it should not (gcc makes it better). I found the solution in making the array ``volatile uint64_t a[64]``, but this can only be considered as workaround to artificially avoid optimization. I didn't find another solution other than that. A pity the OP is closed. I would have loved to answer in order to explain what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Summary:**

MSVS/Release (default solution properties) optimization will change this code ...

```
// Code 1
...
int q = 5;
uint64_t a[32];
// a[] is filled with data
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    a[q] = (a[q] << 2) | 8;
    // printf("%i \n", i); // that's the line which makes it work
}
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    a[q] = (a[q] << 3) | 3;
}
...
```

... into the following one, which is not the same as ...

```
// Code 2
...
int q = 5;
uint64_t a[32];
// a[] is filled with data
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    a[q] = (a[q] << 2) | 8;
    a[q] = (a[q] << 3) | 3;
}
...
```

Above excerpt is slightly simplified, since not limited to constant 32 loops, but kept variable (% 8). Hence 64-bit constants can't be used as commented by a user.

**Discoveries:**

MSVS/Release - fails
MSVS/Debug - works
gcc/Release - works
gcc/Debug - works

MSVS/Release optimization merges the two `for()` loops (Code 1) into one `for()` loop (Code 2).

**Fixes:**

The commented `printf()` provides an artificial fix this as the compiler sees the requirement to print an intermediate result.

An alternative fix would be to to use the type qualifier `volatile` for `a[]`.

The root of the issue is, that MSVS optimization doesn't consider that the index `q` remains the same in both loops, meaning that the first loop needs to finish before the second loop starts.